# Community detection on weighted graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The documentation says that `FindGraphCommunities` works with weighted graphs. I've been playing around with a complete graph with weighted edges, and `FindGraphCommunities` always returns a single community, as if it wasn't taking into account the weights of the edges.

Can someone explain how I can do a community detection on a weighted graph using Mathematica?

Comment: The next version of IGraph/M will have many community detection functions that work with weighted graphs, and could use some testing before release ... https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a graph similar to the weighted graph example in the documentation [FindGraphCommuinities >> Scope](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindGraphCommunities.html):

```
vl = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
el = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 
      5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 7, 6 <-> 8, 7 <-> 8};
vc = {{3.24, 0.86}, {3.24, 0.02}, {2.2, 0.88}, {2.2, 0.}, {1.04, 0.88},
      {1.04, 0.}, {0., 0.86}, {0., 0.02}};

ew1 = {0.3, 0.9, 0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 1., 0.6, 0.8, 0.7};
g1 = Graph[vl, el, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
   EdgeWeight -> ew1, EdgeLabels -> Thread[el -> ew1], ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 500];
Row[{g1, Style[FindGraphCommunities[g1], 16, "Panel"]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Now, randomly re-shuffle the edge weights:

```
ew2 = RandomSample[ew1];
g2 = Graph[vl, el, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
   EdgeWeight -> ew2, EdgeLabels ->Thread[el -> ew2], ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 500];
Row[{g2, Style[FindGraphCommunities[g2], 16, "Panel"]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Addressing the question in the comments:

> Vertices connected with larger `EdgeWeights` are considered closer or farther  (that is, larger EdgeWeights pull vertices to the same community or to distinct communities)?

Holding everything else fixed, observe how graph communities change  as the `EdgeWeight` of the edge `3 <-> 5` changes from `0` to `5`:

```
Manipulate[
 ew2 = {0.3`, 0.9`, 0.1`, 0.4`, ew35, 0.5`, 1.`, 0.6`, 0.8`, 0.7`};
 g2 = Graph[vl, el, VertexLabels -> Thread[vl -> 
             (Placed[Style[#, "Panel", 16, Black, Background -> None], Center] & /@ vl)],
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", VertexSize -> .2, 
   EdgeWeight -> ew2, EdgeStyle -> Thick, 
   EdgeLabels -> Flatten[{Thread[el -> (Style[#, "Panel", 16, Red] & /@ ew1)], 
                       el[[5]] -> Style[ew2[[5]], Bold, "Panel", 20, Purple]}],
   ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 500];
 gc = FindGraphCommunities[g2];
 Column[{Style[gc, 16, "Panel"], HighlightGraph[g2, gc]}, Alignment -> Center], 
{ew35, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Two questions: EdgeWeights have to be between 0 and 1? Vertices connected with larger EdgeWeights are considered closer or farther (that is, larger EdgeWeights pull vertices to the same community or to distinct communities)?

Comment: @becko, They don't have be between 0 and 1; the weights seem to be automatically scaled/normalized (try multiplying the weights by any number). Re larger vs. smaller EdgeWeights, I don't know what the convention is - but my intuition is that weights indicate "strength of connection" rather than "distance", so I would expect larger edge weight between two nodes would make more likely that they will be in the same community, but I am not sure (We can experiment with the numbers in the posted example).

Comment: I think this interpretation of `EdgeWeights` in `FindGraphCommunities` is inconsistent to that in `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`. In `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` a weight of `Infinity` means that the vertices are not linked, whereas in `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` it means that they are strongly connected!

Comment: @becko, right. It seems there is not _a single_ context-free interpretation of `EdgeWeight`s.

Comment: ... in fact,  [EdgeWeight>>Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeWeight.html) says: _The weight Subscript[w, i] can be interpreted as cost or capacity, or can have other special meanings for different graph computation functions._