# Which algorithms are implemented in community detection based on AdjacencyGraph[.] and WeightedAdjacencyGraph[.]?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm

The following code generates two distinct community structures: one uses a simple adjacency matrix (with 1 and 0), another uses a weighted adjacency graph (with positive real numbers). I like to know which `Algorithms` Mathematica implements in each case, and where they are documented (references to articles). [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65918/60365) gives a relevant explanation for my question but it does not give any reference explaining the method. There must be a reference to algorithms implemented!

```
ClearAll[mat, g, wmat, wag];

SeedRandom[123];

(* communities from an unweighted adjacency graph *)
mat = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {25, 25}];
g = AdjacencyGraph[mat /. (0. -> Infinity), VertexLabels -> "Name"];
WeightedGraphQ[g]
FindGraphCommunities[g]

(* communities from a weighted adjacency graph *)
wmat = (mat*RandomReal[{1, 5}, {25, 25}]) /. (0. -> Infinity);
wag = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[wmat, DirectedEdges -> True, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];
WeightedGraphQ[wag]
FindGraphCommunities[wag]

Row[{CommunityGraphPlot[g, ImageSize -> 350], 
  CommunityGraphPlot[wag, ImageSize -> 350]}]
```

In the following link S. Horvat was also raising the same question like mine:

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1267979

Comment: Why don't you use IGraph/M? All the community detection algorithms have references, and the code is open.